# Angular Material DatePicker Autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete, datepicker, angular-material

trying to implement a searchbar where you can search by the item's name or by a date. just wanted to know if there's a way to disable the datepicker autocomplete?

problem is :
- if i do a search by date, it's fine
- if i do a search by name it's ok...  untill i loose focus of search input, then it autocomplete with a date

example :
if i search an item with 1234 in it and loose focus of the search input, it will complete with 01/01/1234 and do the research with it...

```
   <mat-form-field id="search">
      <input i18n-placeholder="Search@@searchBar" matInput placeholder="Search..."
      [matDatepicker]="picker" (dateInput)="searchDate($event)"  #input />
      <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>

    <span>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker ></mat-datepicker>
    </span>
```

Maybe i'm just doing it the wrong way...?
Regards
j0w

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.io

Comment: i'll just redirrect you to the doc examples where you can see it happens too i you start typing a date then loose focus of the input field : https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: if you enter 123 then go out of the field you'll get 1/1/123. that's what i'd like to prevent for my case

Comment: I have provided an answer, feel free to check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create an hidden input, bound to the datepicker, and update the value of the autocomplete when the user choses a date. The first input, on the other side, should not be bound to the datepicker, since it is an autocomplete. Here is a [**stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1lpzty?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.ts) :

```js
toFormattedDate(iso: string) {
  const date = new Date(iso);
  console.log(date);
  return `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput #autocomplete placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<input type="hidden" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" (dateChange)="autocomplete.value = toFormattedDate($event.value)">
```

Comment: Thanks @trichetriche for your answer! I modified it a bit by using ` return formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'fr-FR' ).toString();` from `import { formatDate } from '@angular/common'` and it seems to work perfectly!

Comment: Thanks, seems like an easy way. For me, as in your stackblitz example, the problem is that the datepicker popup is positioned on position 0,0 and not under the input-field.

Comment: @hgoebl never encountered that. Please make a question with a [mcve], if you're looking for a resolution on it !

Comment: It's not a question, just a comment. The stackblitz is already a minimal reproducable example for not showing the popup under the visible date input field (Chrome 74, Win7). No action required for me.

Comment: Can somebody tell me now how to do it with multiple languages so multiple dateFormats? That does not work for me. Especially I need a validator for the input of the date now, if a user can type in the date