# Angular Material DatePicker user input error with autocomplete

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

There is a already known issue with the `mat-datepicker` but the solution is not working perfectly for me because I got different date formats depending on the current selected language of the website.

[Angular Material DatePicker Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514645/angular-material-datepicker-autocomplete)

So this is the "solution" that's been given for me. I want the user to be able to also type in the date and not just use the datePicker because why should have an input field which does not work. But yes like the question above said:

Example : if i search an item with 1234 in it and loose focus of the search input, it will complete with 01/01/1234 and do the research with it...

With this solution I can type in everything into the input field. But if I'm entering something wrong the browser console logs:

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "27.08.1999" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

But the form does not show any error like everything is perfect because it's not validated. Another issue with the solution above is that any selection in the datepicker will end in this format `10/11/2005` but I want to have the german format `dd.MM.YYYY`

Please notice that my version already contain the changes of the solution above.

**StackBlitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5k42x

**HTML**:

```html
 <mat-form-field class="field-sizing">
   <input matInput #autocomplete required [max]="globals.currentDate"
     placeholder="{{ 'REGISTRATION.DATEOFBIRTH' | translate }}" name="dateOfBirth"
     formControlName="dateOfBirth"
     [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': g.dateOfBirth.touched && g.dateOfBirth.errors }" />
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateOfBirthPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #dateOfBirthPicker startView="multi-year" [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
   <mat-error class="invalid-feedback"
     *ngIf="g.dateOfBirth.touched && g.dateOfBirth.errors && g.dateOfBirth.errors.required">
     {{ 'REGISTRATION.DATEOFBIRTH' | translate }} {{ 'VALIDATION.REQUIRED' | translate }}
   </mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>


 <input type="hidden" [matDatepicker]="dateOfBirthPicker"
   (dateChange)="autocomplete.value = toFormattedDate($event.value)">
```

**TypeScript**:

```js
   public personalForm: FormGroup;

   get g() {
     return this.personalForm.controls;
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.buildForm();
   }

   public buildForm() {
     this.personalForm = this.form.group({
       dateOfBirth: ['', [Validators.required]],
     })
   }

   toFormattedDate(iso: string) {
     const date = new Date(iso);
     console.log(date);
     return `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
   }

  constructor(
     public form: FormBuilder
   ) { }
```

Comment: Better to have your code in stackblitz, Seems the error in this line (dateChange)="autocomplete.value = toFormattedDate($event.value)".

Comment: Yes of course it is in this line. Because the format does just work for a specific format and there is also no validation for a correct input. I can try later to create a StackBlitz

Comment: First you need to do the validation before you try Date(iso) right? and try moment js if the date format that you're trying not available in angular.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5k42x Here is the stackBlitz @Harshana

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error with the attached stackblitz hope this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905033/pre-populating-and-validating-date-in-angular-6-reactive-form helps you to validate your input before convert it to a Date object. And, you can use a custom validator function to indicate the error in UI.